# Folder layout created during Python installation

Tags: python

In the main folder where Python is installed there are

```
Python26
  -DLLs
  -Doc
  -include
  -Lib
  -libs
  -Scripts
  -tcl
  -Tools
```

What is each of these supposed to be?  Why is there `libs` and `Libs`?  Why do some things go in `Lib\site-packages` like Django and others like sqlite3 in `Lib`?  An explanation of how things are decided or a pointer to an article would be helpful if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLLs: contains the Dynamic Link Libraries (windows only) for python and its extensions. only important if you're extending or embedding python
-Doc: Python documentation
-include: include files for extending python
-Lib: the python libraries (things like pickle, email, cgi, etc.)
-libs: Not quite sure about this one. I think it's mostly the c/c++ parts of python extensions
-Scripts: Useful scripts (easy_install and the like)
-tcl: For the tkinter gui library
-Tools: More useful scripts.

The reason that sqlite3 is in Lib and django is in Lib/site-packages is that sqlite3 is a builtin module. Django, on the other hand, is a extension to python, installed separately from python.

Comment: thank you pyhacker!  that helps in my understanding of the system